# How to create a HTTP POST to HTTPs with a .pem file

Tags: rest, curl, amazon-ec2, https

I created a web service on an EC2 machine on AWS. I want to do HTTP POSTs to it, via a tool (think Postman) that does raw HTTP posts. However the web service is using https, so i get 302 responses as unauthorized, as i don't know how to authenticate. 
I can post using the -k option to bypass the security verification:

```
$ curl -k  -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "attr0":2, "attr1":0, "attr2":0 }' "https://ec2-x-x-x.compute.amazonaws.com:XX/queries.json"
```

Is there a way to make a raw HTTP POST, bypassing cert validation, akin to passing a -k in the HTTP headers perhaps ? Perl seems to have a similar mechanism, so i am thinking there is a way to do this "raw" in a HTTP header.

Option #2 is to make the call with the security key that i can generate from AWS, but this seems very complicated for just testing a Web service. Any way to circumvent this ? This is just for playing around, not an actual production service..

```
$ curl --cert /home/ubuntu/aws_file.pem  -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "attr0":2, "attr1":0, "attr2":0 }' "https://ec2-x-x-x.compute.amazonaws.com:XX/queries.json"
curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

Any help?
Matt

Comment: What kind of pem file are you referring to? (PEM is only an encoding standard that specifies the way data is stored in the file, not what the specific data actually consists of).  If it's the ssh key for the instance, that of course will not work.  Fundamentally, though, it's unclear *who* you're talking about authenticating. The latter part of the question implies authenticating the client (you) but `-k` (an alias for `--insecure`) disables authentication of the *server* (by ignoring mismatched certificates) -- not of you.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot , yes i am talking about the .pem file from AWS, which is (i realized now) is the ssh key for the instance, and will not work. Essentially i want to bypass the server's check in a REST API , similar to what is done in a curl -k command ..

Comment: Altbough I may be misunderstanding what you are referring to, I think you may be confused about what you are calling the "server's check."  It sounds like yoi are talking about the *client-side* validation of the server's certificate.  To help me understand, please describe what happens now -- what is it that doesn't work, what are the symptoms of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: ok i reformulated my query..

Comment: *"302 responses as unauthorized"*...?  HTTP status 302 is `Found` or `Moved Temporarily`.  Can you clarify what you mean, here?  And perhaps add a screen shot to try to help explain the broken behavior?

Comment: Sorry, meant 403.